# reading a file into a dictionary to check the number of repeated words

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write python code to read a file, create a dictionary from the content and then check the number of repeated words. The code is below with comments about each step:

```
import string

# making a dictionary from a paragraph
def make_dict(s):
    some_list = s.split()
    d = dict()
    for word in some_list:             
        d[word] = 1 + d.get(word,0)
    print d
    print
    print
    return d

#Inverse the dictionary
# swap between key and value

def invert_dict(s):
    inverse = {}
    d = make_dict(s)
    for key in d:
        val =  d[key]
        if val not in inverse:
            inverse[val] = [key]
        else:
            inverse[val].append(key)
    print inverse
    print
    print
    return inverse


# Reading a file and copying just plain text in other file    
def make_text():
    file_name = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
    fn = open(file_name)
    for line in fn:
        line = line.translate(None,"!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~")
        line = line.lower()
        some_text = open('duplicate.txt','a')
        some_text.write(line)
       # print some_text
        some_text.close()
        fn.close()
        return some_text


some_file = make_text()
some_dict =  invert_dict(some_file)
for key in some_dict:
    print key , some_dict[key]
    print
```

When I run the code, I got the following error. Can someone please help explain what am I doing wrong, and how to fix the error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\Python practice\DataStructureSelectionb\string_to_dictionary.py", line 51, in <module>
    some_dict =  invert_dict(some_file)
  File "C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\Python practice\DataStructureSelectionb\string_to_dictionary.py", line 22, in invert_dict
    d = make_dict(s)
  File "C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\Python practice\DataStructureSelectionb\string_to_dictionary.py", line 8, in make_dict
    some_list = s.split()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `make_text` function returns the (closed) file object it has written to, not a string like you seem to expect. Perhaps you want to return `line` instead?

It's also unclear if you actually want to return from within the loop at all, since that will only process the first line from the file the user named for you. If you want to read the whole file, rather than just a single line, I'd call `fn.read()` rather than iterating on `fn` (who's name is a bit misleading, since it's a file object, not a just a file name). Alternatively you might want `make_text` to be a generator function, `yield`ing each line (but this would require significant changes in your other code).